# Lisp 4-in-a-row game

Tags: list, lisp, common-lisp

I have the following board which represents a 4-in-a-row game.

`(defun board1 ()
    '((NIL NIL NIL NIL)
     (NIL NIL NIL NIL)
     (NIL NIL NIL NIL)
     (NIL NIL NIL NIL)))`

Is there any way to convert it inside the program to the board below? Assume that one NIL in the board1 is the same as a (NIL NIL NIL NIL) in board2.

`(defun board2 ()
    '(((NIL NIL NIL NIL)(NIL NIL NIL NIL)(NIL NIL NIL NIL)(NIL NIL NIL NIL))
    ((NIL NIL NIL NIL)(NIL NIL NIL NIL)(NIL NIL NIL NIL)(NIL NIL NIL NIL))
    ((NIL NIL NIL NIL)(NIL NIL NIL NIL)(NIL NIL NIL NIL)(NIL NIL NIL NIL))
    ((NIL NIL NIL NIL)(NIL NIL NIL NIL)(NIL NIL NIL NIL)(NIL NIL NIL NIL)))`

If I could convert it, in this way I could re-use my code already done for board2 which allows me to put pieces on it, and make breath-first, bread-first and A* searches for the fastest solution.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: "Is there ...?" -> Yes.

Comment: You're returning quoted data. You are (probably, it's not clear from the code given) looking at mutating this later. Mutating quoted data is likely going to end in sorrow.

Answer (score 1):

You should learn about literals. Literals should not be modified. So don't make game boards with `quote`. Read this: http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/s_quote.htm.

If you want to reuse board1, you can do

```
(loop repeat 4 collect (mapcar 'copy-seq (board1)))
```

But why not just do this:

```
(loop repeat 4 collect (loop repeat 4 collect (make-list 4)))
```